# UICollectionView delegate not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have custom `UICollectionViewController`, `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, and `UICollectionViewCell` classes.  In my layout I have stacked each section similar to http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial .

Currently all data is displayed correctly when I run the app.

I am trying to implement `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` in my controller to initiate a seque based on the tapped item.  However the delegate method never gets called.  Inside my custom cell class I have added a `touchesEnded` method that DOES get called, but I can not figure out why the delegate in my view controller class is not firing.

Under my `UICollectionViewController` class I have specified protocols `<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>`.  In `viewDidLoad`I have also specified:

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

As a side note, but I think it's a related problem - in Storyboard I have my prototype cell.  It's class type is set to my custom class, and I have set the `ReuseIdentifier`.  In my view controller I load my custom cell class and use the same `ReuseIdentifier`.  However there is a disconnect between StoryBoard and the Cell class.  I can make changes to the storyboard prototype cell and they are not reflected in what happens at runtime.  Instead, I have to comment out the line:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[NSideCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:NSIDE_CELL_IDENTIFIER];
```

To force it to use my storyboard cell version.  But when I do that, my `initWithFrame` custom initialization code in my cell class never gets called.  I'm not sure why this is the case since Storyboard clearly shows my prototype cell has the correct class type.

Comment: What does your custom cell look like?  Do you have something like a UITextView covering much of the cell that might be intercepting touches?

Comment: Do you have `[super touchesEnded:touches]` in your custom class?

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question - items created in storyboard call initWithCoder instead of initWithFrame.  Commenting out the explicit custom cell class registration allows the view controller to follow what was set up in storyboard and everything works as expected.

Comment: You can also use the method "awakeFromNib"